# How to select specific words from a HTML webpage to append to a data frame in R?

Tags: html, r, dataframe

I'm building this **scraper** to pull game data from this webpage:https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201410280LAL.html The **scraper** pulls all the information for the home and away team for this matchup but does not indicate the actual name of the team that the players play for just their names and stats

Below is my **scraper** so far which pulls basic and advanced stats for the home and away team, shapes it into a data frame and drops rows that are not player names and their stats or the team total, and converts the proper columns into their respective variable types.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201410280LAL.html"
webpage <- read_html(url)
tbls <- webpage %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table(header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) 
tbls <- tbls %>% lmap( ~ set_names(.x, nm = pluck(.x, 1, 1, 1))) %>% map(~ set_names(.x, nm = .x[2, ]))
awaybas <- tbls %>% .[1]
awayadv <- tbls %>% .[2] 
homebas <- tbls %>% .[3] 
homeadv <- tbls %>% .[4] 
ab1 <- as.data.frame(awaybas)
aa1 <- as.data.frame(awayadv)
hb1 <- as.data.frame(homebas)
ha1 <- as.data.frame(homeadv)
ab <- ab1[-c(1,2,8),]
aa <- aa1[-c(1,2,8),]
hb <- hb1[-c(1,2,8),]
ha <- ha1[-c(1,2,8),]
ab[,c(3:21)] <- sapply(ab[,c(3:21)], as.numeric)
aa[,c(3:16)] <- sapply(aa[,c(3:16)], as.numeric)
hb[,c(3:21)] <- sapply(hb[,c(3:21)], as.numeric)
ha[,c(3:16)] <- sapply(ha[,c(3:16)], as.numeric)
```

This code runs fine but I want to pull the Team name abbreviations and add them to their respective dataframes(For this game it would be HOU and LAL) but am not sure how to pull that information from the other parts of the HTML webpage

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look in the website and assuming that all the html pages that you are interested have the same structure, I think this may solve your question:

```
abbr <- webpage %>% 
  html_nodes('strong') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  .[5:6]
```